# Как задать определенное количество символов используя C# Random

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день. Я новичок в программировании. Столкнулся с проблемой.
Как можно задать определенный объём символов при использовании функции Рандом.
Вот пример кода в котором массив чисел заполняется в случайном порядке 0 или 1.

Хотелось бы сделать возможность задать параметры распределения. Как пример, чтобы 80% массива были 0. При этом чтобы остался случайным порядок заполнения

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
{
    newArray[i] = randomGen.Next(0, 2)
    if (newArray[i] == 0)
    {
        newArray[i] = black;
    }
    else
    {
        newArray[i] = white;                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

К сожалению, «из коробки» такого решения нет. Но можно легко смоделировать.

Например, если мы хотим вероятность нуля 80%:

```
var percent = randomGen.Next(0, 100); // от 0 до 99
if (percent < 80)
    newArray[i] = black;
else
    newArray[i] = white;
```

---

Для большего количества альтернатив, например, 60% чёрного, 30% красного, 6% зелёного и 4% белого:

```
var percent = randomGen.Next(0, 100); // от 0 до 99
if (percent < 60)                 // [0..60) => black
    newArray[i] = black;
else if (percent < 60 + 30)       // [60..90) => red
    newArray[i] = red;
else if (percent < 60 + 30 + 6)   // [90..96) => green
    newArray[i] = green;
else                              // [96..100) => white
    newArray[i] = white;
```

Ну и так далее.

Comment: Другой вариант - заполнить массив числами в нужной пропорции, а затем перемешать случайным образом, тогда пропорция будет соблюдена точно.

Comment: @Андрей: Это может быть дорого, если отношения вероятностей неприятные. Например, 13.1% / 86.9% заставят заводить массив из тысячи элементов. А так вообще да, тоже способ. Можно даже не перемножать, а просто выбрать элемент по случайному индексу.

Comment: Как я понял, у автора задача заполнить массив

Comment: @Андрей: А, вы в этом смысле! А если длина массива не делится на процент? Ну например, массив длиной в 1?

Comment: Тогда задача невыполнима. Ну или нужно определить допуски )

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, если речь идёт о _случайном_ заполнении, то в принципе проблем нет.